# What is the best way to make the B shape in this gif?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am modelling a set of stairs:
[image: An image of some untextured stairs]

and wish to turn them into a high polygon model to resemble this with clear spaces between the bricks and all bricks to be of the same size:

[image: A textured model of stairs]

I saw the below gif from [Rigid Body Dynamic Animation Problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141468/rigid-body-dynamic-animation-problem/141678#141678) but no way to reproduce the B it so that the model is made up of cubes with the edges of the model being smoothed or curved to fit the original mesh.

[image: A gif of a B made of cubes being smashed]

So far all I have is this built from arrays (I am aware I'll need many more) from this tutorial [Destroying any object into cubes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/destroying-any-object-into-cubes) but my blender locks up for quite a long time and has yet to finish processing it:

[image: some bevelled cubes]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello :). So are you asking how to do the stairs or how to do the letter B?

Comment: i think both :D

Comment: to make a b with cubes you could make a text "b", convert it to mesh, then remesh modifier and then instancing (vertices)

Comment: The B is simply the method I want to use, the stairs is how I want the shape to look. The remesh modifier doesn't keep the shape, it warps it with just about every way I fiddle with it.

Comment: I have created this [https://i.imgur.com/4MEh75N.png]   with that advice, but I don't think it's the correct method. It's not warping the shapes to fit, just adjusting their rotations.

Comment: In short, how do I do this? [https://i.imgur.com/lROdM24.png]

Comment: the remesh modifier does keep the shape. you just have to use it right. Tutorial:https://youtu.be/ILvt60KJsRM

Comment: I get a different, but similar and not quite correct result. Again, it doesn't warp, cut or edit the shapes only aligns them to the templated staircase. So the edges are jagged when they should be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I decided to use [Destroying any object into cubes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/destroying-any-object-into-cubes) and breaking the model into a more simple geometry for my computer to handle.