# Divide any high poly object into cubes

Tags: particles, boolean-modifier

I’m trying to figure out how to divide any organic high poly object into cube shards. Like an island.

I've tried the solution in this post "[Destroying any high poly object into cubes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97721/destroying-any-object-into-cubes?newreg=c9c36b4cf1dc4ffa80122bebb8597f38)" but I have some artifacts.

I've tried to cut this island (349k faces) with no success, the smaller the cube size the more errors appear.

[image]

Comment: Any chance the remesh modifier set to voxel would work for this?  Or do the cubes have to be separate objects?

Comment: They have to be separate objects because I need to work with each part separately. The remesh boxel will not work for my purpose; I need the objects to retain its original high-poly form